# How to maintain aspect ratio of html container using only CSS

Tags: html, css

The title is a little misleading since simply maintaining the aspect ratio of and html element is trivial, using width and padding-bottom or padding-top in percentages. However, my scenario is a little different. Maybe the solution is just as trivial but my brain is fried.

So in my case, I have a content div inside a container div. The assumption is that the container div can have any dimensions and size. The requirement is that the inner div needs to maintain it's own aspect ratio but needs to also fit either the height or the width of the container div, whichever corresponds closer to the aspect ratio of the content div.

So for example, my content div has aspect ratio 16:9. My container div is currently 500px wide and 1000px high. In this case, my content div would size itself to 500px wide and 281px high, with white space above and below the content div. Now the container div might get resized to 1000px wide and 500px high, in which case the content div would resize itself to 889px width and 500px height, with white space to the left and right of the content div.

There's probably a less convoluted way to explain this scenario but again, my brain is fried today. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am looking for a CSS only solution. I know that this is possible with JS/JQuery.

Comment: You need some jquery, it goes well with it

Comment: This was not possible for replaced elements with intrinsic aspect ratio, so they had to introduce [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). So I guess it's not possible for non-replaced elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is use something like `object-fit: cover` to have the best looking effects in your case. Unfortunately, a CSS-only solution in this case will not give the desired results, as stated above, JavaScript/jQuery is needed.